# Why implement specific functions to retrieve data rather than retrieving directly when overloading a * operator for a iterator class nested in a ADT

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, iterator

C++ newbie here.

I'm reading the book Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++(M. A. Weiss), where the implementation of const_iterator and iterator class nested in a user-defined List class of `<typename Object>` was given.

Here's a snippet of it.

```
class const_iterator
{
public:
    const Object& operator* () const
    { return retrieve(); }

protected:
    Node* current_;

    Object& retrieve() const
    { return current_->data_; }
};

class iterator : public const_iterator
{
public:
    Object& operator* ()
    { return const_iterator::retrieve(); }

    const Object& operator* () const
    { return const_iterator::operator*(); }
};
```

I really don't get why did the author bother to write the `retrieve` function just to retrieve the data, whose body is exactly all it takes to do so. If I were to implement the three overload functions, I would naturally write `return current_->data_` or `return *this->current_->data_`. I mean, even if it's equivalent, I wouldn't come up with this kind of idea either.

This question seems trivial, and I'm asking out of pure curiosity. In my limited knowledge of C++, calling functions has a performance cost. Though this could be optimized out by the compiler, I prefer the code to be logically the most efficient at least on paper.

It gets even stranger that for const return values, the author used `operator*` instead of `retrieve` in consistency.

What's the benefit of jumping between retrieve functions rather than a simple return expression?

Comment: Using `operator*()` is consistent with the expected interface of an iterator. Your code snippet doesn't qualify as a [mre], since there are a few names unaccounted for. My take is that the inheritance structure is backwards, but the better way to implement a Standard Library compliant iterator is to use the tools provided by the Standard Library, which this also does not do. Likely because it would over-complicate the principle they are attempting to teach.

Comment: To actually answer your headline question, it accounts for polymorphism. The better example for just the question headline would be a printing objects in an inheritance structure. The base class would handle all the common printing, and then make a call to a virtual function for any sub-object-specific information.

Comment: is the book perhaps talking about other iterators in the following sections? Eg a `reverse_iterator` might overload `retrieve`. Though its still a bit fishy that nothing is `virtual` in the code. I have to ask again: Is this really the exact code as printed in the book?

Comment: "In my limited knowledge of C++, calling functions has a performance cost." That's not generally true, `retrieve` is very likely to be inlined

Comment: @sweenish What do you need bro, I'm trying to keep the code compact, otherwise it could take a rather large amount of space.

Comment: what we need: [mcve]

Comment: if you do not understand the code you cannot remove pieces from it and be sure that omitting those pieces does not change the meaning completely. Please make sure to post the code as is

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The author intended not to use the keyword ```virtual```, I checked it again. It should be the exact code. The naming is a little different, adjusted to my taste

Comment: @sweenish the inheritance is the right way round to me. There's an implicit conversion from mutable to const, but not from const to mutable

Comment: The whole implementation is pages long, I'm sorry if I did not provide any key information you might need, please just name it.

Comment: for one, it is a `const_iterator` for `Object`, ie it is useless as generic iterator for any other type. As this code is practically useless, I'd expect that it comes with lots of text to explain what the code is supposed to demonstrate (because a working implementation it is not). Is it really not a template?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is a template, a user-defined List class of```typename Object```. The iterator is nested in it.

Comment: well, such context is necessary to understand what is going on.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is there also a reverse_iterator?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Nah, it's left as an exercise and is not related to the ```retrieve``` function. Would you mind clearing some of the comments to keep the section neat?

Comment: why do you think it is not related to the `retrieve` function? It is.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I mean the author did not associate it with the ```retrieve``` function.

Comment: consider what a reverse_iterator has to do different. It needs no different implementation of `operator*` or of its const overload. It only needs a different implementation of `retrieve` and can inherit `operator*` as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usage of intermediary function may just be due to the preference of the author. Usually such style is used in order to perform some validation in the intermediary function(for example, checking if data_ is `nullptr`, or if data_ satisfies some condition which is imposed by the problem the code tries to solve). But I have seen some people who even if there is no need for some kind of validation, still use this style. For example when you write

```
Object& operator* ()
{ return const_iterator::retrieve(); }
```

you expect that retrieve function will not return you corrupted data. And even when you get a corrupted value, you immediately know that there is a problem in `retrieve` function, and you can just solve the issue by investigating it. If you didn't have an intermediary function, you had to investigate every place where you written the alternative code of retrieve. Also, it is much better to have a function which deals with all the raw data, and you don't deal with them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A large advantage of funnelling everything through `retrieve` is that it is *one place*.

If you want to change the behaviour, you change it in the one place. If you want a debugger to stop there, it's one breakpoint.

Comment: Both of you helped me. Hope you don't mind I chose the other guy XD, who has a more detailed reasoning.